# Need to be able to convert nvarchar date to date format without time showing on frontend

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, webforms

I am dealing with a SQL Server 2008 r2 database where the create date and time are in separate fields and each is of a data type of nvarchar.  I know this is horrible, but I am stuck with this structure for now and can't change the database.  I am returning this create date from the database(using stored procedures) to the frontend, which is an asp.net webform page.  This data is being bound to a GridView.

Once in this Grid view, the user would like to be able to click on this date and sort the rows by date.  Obviously this is currently not working since the date is in varchar format.  So I am trying to convert this date in the stored procedure to some valid date format, like datetime, and return it to the front end as a valid dateformat.  This way I can then sort by date properly.

The good news is I have been able to do this, but the bad news is that when I convert the nvarchar date to a datetime object, I keep getting a time of something like 00:00:0.  I have researched this and no matter what I  do I can't get rid of this time.  All I need is the date in a valid date format.  I don't need the time.  Can someone show me how to convert it to a date without the time?

Comment: You can use the string format : `yourDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` in the display part.

Comment: I don't think that will work for me.  The date is part of a dataset which is being bound to a GridView control.  I can't use string formatting in the column definition either I believe, as I need the value to be a date object.

Comment: See my answer for `.aspx` part. It will handle your databound field from your `DataSet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to apply text format in grdivew is use the DataFormatString property of the gridview boundfield.
like shown below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" 
                    HeaderText="Date" 
                    DataFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy" />
           </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The combination of converting to a date in SQL server and using the DataFormatString solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string format for dates as below...

```
//For .cs code
lblDate.Text = yourDateField.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

<%-- For .aspx markup --%>
<asp:label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("yourDateField")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>' />
```

And use your Stored procedure to short on dates.

**EDIT**

Of course you can format any field from the `DataSet`, which is bound to a `GridView` as a `DataSource`.

Put the below markup in your `GridView` in `.aspx` page...

```
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("yourDateField")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>
```